# Start Animation With Screen Loading - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm making a **Splash Screen** in my app.

In my splash screen, I want to animate(zoom in) my logo

I want to animate my logo, as soon as the screen starts.

This is my code so far...

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  final _splashDelay = 2000;
  double _height = 10.0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _loadWidget();
  }

  _loadWidget() async {
    var _duration = Duration(milliseconds: _splashDelay);
    return Timer(_duration, navigationPage); 
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.red[900]);
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(true);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 15,
                vertical: 30,
              ),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 4.5,
                child: Center(
                  child: AnimatedContainer(
                    duration: Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                    height: _height,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

> What I want is, to change the height of the `AnimatedContainer()` from **10 to 100** as soon as this screen starts.

I've been trying to achieve this since 3hrs now, but couldn't help myself get through. Now I'm seeking for your help/guidance. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You must create an AnimationController and TweenAnimation that goes from the begin (10) to the end (100).
In this case, the controller is just for (redundant, I know) control the animation and when it should start.

When you create a Tween, and apply the method animate() you're just saying that you want the animation to start at the begin of this tween and end at the end of it within the time that you specified in the controller Duration.

```
final _splashDelay = 2000;
Animation height;
AnimationController _controller;
@override
void initState() {
  // TODO: implement initState
  super.initState();
  _controller=AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds:_splashDelay,),)..forward();
  _controller.addListener(
    () {
      setState(() {});
    },
  );
  height=Tween<double>(begin:10, end:100,).animate(_controller);
  _loadWidget();
}
```

Then, when you're building your AnimatedContainer, you must provide height: _height.value

Here you're just saying "Flutter, please change the value of this variable from 10 to 100 in a 2000 milliseconds interval, and use this value to draw the height of this Container"

Please note the you must add the mixin SingleTickerProviderStateMixin to your state. If you don't, vsync: this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `ScaleTransition` widget to achieve your goal.

You can checkout the working sample of your code below:

```
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SplashScreenState createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final _splashDelay = 2000;
  double _height = 10.0;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: const Duration(seconds: 2));
    _animationController.forward();
    super.initState();
    _loadWidget();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  _loadWidget() async {
    var _duration = Duration(milliseconds: _splashDelay);
    return Timer(_duration, navigationPage);
  }

  void navigationPage() {
    Navigator.pushReplacement(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LoginScreen()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarColor(Colors.red[900]);
    FlutterStatusbarcolor.setStatusBarWhiteForeground(true);
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: double.infinity,
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 15,
                vertical: 30,
              ),
              child: Card(
                elevation: 4.5,
                child: Center(
                  child: ScaleTransition(
                    scale: _animationController,
                    child: Image.asset('assets/images/logo.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```